# Fatal error: Method name must be a string

Tags: php, oop, fatal-error

I'm getting error:

> Fatal error: Method name must be a string in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 15"

LINE 15:

```
$obj = new $url[0]();
```

CODE:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);

$url = $_GET['url'];
$url = explode('/', $url);

if (!file_exists('controllers/' . $url[0] . '.php')) {
    $url[0] = 'error';   // error kontroleris 
}    
require 'controllers/' . $url[0] . '.php';

$obj = new $url[0]();
$obj->$url[1]();
```

BTW.: Script is not finished yet.

Comment: What version of PHP is this?

Answer (score 2):

Actually, this syntax:

```
$urls = array('DOMDocument');
$dom = new $urls[0]('');
var_dump( $dom );
```

... is valid even in PHP 5.2 ([proof](http://codepad.org/R4Dls2Wz)). But this line...

```
$obj->$url[1]();
```

... is pretty damn able (another [proof](http://codepad.org/sUeOkpFf)) to throw exactly the same error as you've shown, as you don't check for `url` array length anywhere in your code.

Answer (score 0):

```
$_GET['url'] = 'foo/bar'; // temp set $_GET
$url = $_GET['url'];
$url = explode('/', $url);

if (file_exists('controllers/' . $url[0] . '.php')){
    require 'controllers/' . $url[0] . '.php';
}else{
    $url[0] = 'error'; 
}

$obj = new URL;
if(method_exists($obj,$url[0])){ // test that method exists
    echo $obj->$url[0](); // or whatever your handling may be
}

class URL{
    public function error(){
        $return = 'this is for the error handling';
        return $return;
    }
}
```

Comment: Now it says that there is an empty property and it cannot access it :/

Comment: are you ensuring that your using `$obj->url` and not `$obj->$url`

Comment: And then it says that function name must be a string :D

Comment: I've made some edits to the code, on the basis of what i think your trying to achieve

Comment: Now it just says "this is for the error handling"

But it should display the code from two echo'ed controllers

Maybe you have skype ? I would contact you

Comment: you will need to adapt/extend the code, but this should point you in the right direction